# How to use tqdm with while loop if counter is conditionally updated

Tags: python, tqdm

In below code, I want `tqdm` to show progress bar for counter variable `i`. Note that `i` is conditionally updated and the condition or decision to increment itself involves randomness.

```
import random

totalItr = 100
i = 0
actualItr = 0
while i < totalItr:
    actualItr += 1
    if random.choice([True,False]): 
        i += 1
print(actualItr)
```

I tried to explicitly update the tqdm progressbar as below:

```
import random
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

pbar = tqdm(total=100)

totalItr = 100
i = 0
actualItr = 0
while i < totalItr:
    actualItr += 1
    if random.choice([True,False]): 
        i += 1
        pbar.update(1)
pbar.close()
        
print(actualItr)
```

But this does not show any increments in progress bar. Initially it only shows empty progress bar and then after completion of execution it shows green 100% progressbar. What I am missing here?

PS: You can try above code in [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ML-YyUX6tWzuIzmbECKmcHdin3_4z8xi?usp=sharing).

Comment: The code is executed too fast. Just add a `time.sleep(0.05)` to the loop to see something.

Comment: Damn (obviously) that was way to fast! I felt instead of adding `sleep()` I will increase `totalItr`. But I had to set it to `10000000` to see some progress! Lower values of 10s did not show much progress!